# Simulating an if condition in the WHERE clause of an SQL query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to write a google BigQuery to select some records based on this condition:

```
if ID_parameter is not null:
   SELECT * WHERE ID=ID_parameter
else:
   SELECT * WHERE country_id=country_id_parameter and (name LIKE %name_parameter% OR name is null)
```

The name_parameter should be optional but one of the ID_parameter or country_id_parameter must be provided.

Sorry, I am a newbie with SQL but I hope I stated what I want clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider below approach

```
select *
from your_table
where case 
  when not id_parameter is null then id = id_parameter
  else country_id = country_id_parameter and (regexp_contains(name, name_parameter) or name is null)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I miss the table name in the query, let's assume it's 'personnel'.
Suppose ID-parameter = 200, country_id_parameter = 'NL', name_parameter = '%bart%'

Maybe like this when the name is 'bart':

```
select * from personnel 
where ID=200 
or (ID=NULL and
    country_id='NL' and
    name LIKE '%bart%')
```

Use this when the name is NULL:

```
select * from personnel 
where ID=200 
or (ID=NULL and
    country_id='NL')
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine both queries? To use LIKE if the name is not null and to ignore it when it is null? Because I am receiving those parameters from a GET request and I don't have control over them.

Comment: And thank you so much for you help :)

Comment: =NULL will always result into false. Use IS NULL.

Comment: When your program already knows a parameter is NULL, you should not put that in the query. Queries will be much slower when you make them complicated. Best is for each situation to make another query (also other method in your class). Debugging Mysql is also not easier.